istio canary strategy with dynamic routing rules with different apps
we are trying to achieve canary strategy for our micro-services running in aks cluster. we followed a very good article https://medium.com/microsoftazure/canary-release-strategy-using-kubernetes-istio-helm-fb49c0406f07 on this and was able to setup the canary for our miro services.
here we have a header called x-canary enabled to decide and route the traffic over the canary and prod version ( if x-canary: true, then always to canary release version irrespective of the weight set and if the x-canary header is false, the traffic should be to both prod and canary as per weightage set).
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myappnamespace
spec:
  gateways:
    - mesh
    - "istio-system/ingress-gateway"
  hosts:
    - "myapp.myappnamespace.svc.cluster.local"
    - "myapp.services.mydomain.com"
  http:
    - match:
      - headers:
          x-canary:
            exact: "true"
      route:
      - destination:
          host: myapp.myappnamespace.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 8080
          subset: canary    
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/"
      retries:
          attempts: 0
      route:
        - destination:
            host: "myapp.myappnamespace.svc.cluster.local"
            port:
              number: 8080
            subset: production
          weight: 50
        - destination:
            host: "myapp.myappnamespace.svc.cluster.local"
            port:
              number: 8080
            subset: canary
          weight: 50

But Here we are not able to achieve different production ready scenarios like, suppose if we have apps  A and B with primary (A, B) and canary with (A1 and B1)
here we would need dynamic routing scenarios between this apps.
1) Primary A to Primary B

2) Primary A to Canary B1

3) Canary A1 to primary B

4) Canary A1 to Canary B1

here I just took 2 apps as example and there can be many apps running with different prod or canary versions and these routing scenarios should be dynamic
As per documents, I guess I need to use of dynamic Header Propagation and inject headers to the source apps and this need to be veriied by the Destination apps on the receival of the request from Source.

As reported at the following link:
https://www.opsmx.com/blog/how-to-perform-canary-with-argo-rollouts-and-istio-service-mesh/
Istio can split the traffic, but an agent is needed to update the traffic percentage based on some analysis.
So you need istio + argo rollouts.
Istio can be used in two ways:
-By treating two versions of an application, canary (new version) and stable (old version) as two separate services in Kubernetes.
-By treating two versions as the subset of the single application. In this case service in Kubernetes will have two different Deployments attached.
I suppose we are in the second case.
You can find a further guide at the following link:
https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/canary-releases-new-relic-argo-rollouts
I expect you have a destination rule similar to this one:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: rollout-ds
  namespace: myappnamespace
spec:
  host: "myapp.myappnamespace.svc.cluster.local"
  subsets:
  - name: production
    labels:
      version: production
  - name: canary
    labels:
      version: canary

